# How to display all the fields in a complex data column (map type) in Impala?

Tags: parquet, impala

I have a datatable in Impala having a complex column with a structure: key and value. I want to show in each row the entire fields of that column: keys and values for each row, when I SELECT the data.

Desired table:

```
Id,             map_tag
100, {building:yes, type:apartment, street:street_a, number:3} 
101, {building:yes, type:hotel}
102, {building:yes, type: bank}
```

If I use:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(kv_pair) map_tag
FROM (
SELECT dt.id id, CONCAT(cc.key,':',cc.value) kv_pair
FROM datatable dt, datatable.complex_column cc
) T
GROUP BY id
```

Then I get one only Id, instead of many Ids. Here a screenshot of it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Impala Complex Types](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_complex_types.html) doc, *"references to fields within MAP columns use the KEY and VALUE pseudocolumns"*. This doc also provides the syntax to query MAP fields. So a combination of a `SELECT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` should do it:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(kv_pair) map_tag
FROM (
  SELECT dt.id id, CONCAT(cc.key,':',cc.value) kv_pair
  FROM datatable dt, dt.complex_column cc
) T
GROUP BY id

Query submitted at: 2020-08-24 12:34:17 (Coordinator: https://impalac:25000)
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | map_tag                                                 | 
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 102 | building:yes, type:bank                                 |
| 100 | building:yes, type:apartment, street:street_a, number:3 |
| 101 | building:yes, type:hotel                                |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
Fetched 3 row(s) in 0.42s
```

Please note that when referencing a `map` field while doing join, you should use an alias for the "main" table if you did assign it an alias. I.e. in the above example, the inner `SELECT` uses `datatable dt` so the reference to `complex_column` should look like **`dt.complex_column`** (not actual_table.column_name which would be "normal").

Comment: When I run this query I get a lot of information concatenated but only in one row. So basically I get one Id and many info concatenated in the column map_tag.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your questions then. The query suppose to return for each id one string representation of a `map` corresponding to it. Can you edit your post and add a representative data sample and desired outcome?

Comment: I have edited it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I edited the answer, please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem actually. Thank you.